# USPS Tracking API

Tags: java, usps

I am trying to use the USPS tracking API. When I send in a request to the production server, I get a 501 response code.

```
 StringEntity se = new StringEntity( "<AddressValidateRequest USERID=\"xxxxxxxx\"><Address><Address1></Address1><Address2>6406 Ivy Lane</Address2><City>Greenbelt</City><State>MD</State><Zip5></Zip5><Zip4></Zip4></Address></AddressValidateRequest>", HTTP.UTF_8);
    se.setContentType("text/xml");
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); 
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=Verify&XML="); 
    httpPost.setEntity(se); 
    HttpEntity resEntity = httpPost.getEntity();
    System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    System.out.println(response.toString());
```

What can be the problem here?

Comment: any error output from compilation? or from response.tostring? could it be a problem with ssl (https)?

Comment: It's quite unusual for a RESTful API to have a POST URL which ends with a blank GET parameter, are you sure that's the correct URL?

Comment: The USPS tracking API is down tonight. Alas, their services don't have an SLA.

Comment: This is the output I am getting: HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented [Connection: close, Date: Sun, 18 Aug 2013 22:47:10 GMT, Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0, X-Powered-By: ASP.NET, Content-Type: text/html]

Comment: @MrLore  - The url is correct. The link to the usps api documentation is : [link](https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-v3-1d.htm)